# How to Hide a Child View From Parent View when touch outside of Child View in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

i am newbie in iOS i make an app that contain Two Views i want to make when Button Was Pressed then Popup Child View so for this i write a cod e like as

```
-(IBAction)mapButtonPressed:(id)sender
 {
self.mapTypeVIew.hidden=FALSE;
 }
```

and in my `viewDidLoad` method i write as

```
[self.mkMapView addSubview:self.mapTypeVIew];
self.mapTypeVIew.hidden=TRUE;
```

so it was hide on `viewDidLoad` method and only shown when button pressed but here i want when button was pressed and subView is also Shown but i want if user touch outside of subview then subview is also hide for that i write a cod like as

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
NSLog(@"touches began");
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if(![touch.view isKindOfClass:[self.mapTypeVIew class]])
{
    self.mapTypeVIew.hidden=TRUE;
}
}
```

But it is Not hidden please give me Solution for when user touch outside of Child view then it was hide.

thanks.

Comment: I am afraid that your - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  is not calling when user tap on map. Can you please confirm if it is calling or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
   NSLog(@"touches began");
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   if(![touch.view isKindOfClass:[self.mapTypeVIew class]])
   {
      self.mapTypeVIew.hidden = YES;
      self.mapTypeVIew.alpha = 0.0;
   }
}
```

and while showing ,

```
-(IBAction)mapButtonPressed:(id)sender
 {
    self.mapTypeVIew.hidden = NO;
    self.mapTypeVIew.alpha = 1.0;
 }
```

Comment: there is no difference between these 2 line code:       self.mapTypeVIew.hidden = YES;
self.mapTypeVIew.alpha = 0.0;
Both are same. Why u use both line code? can u explain ?

Comment: the difference is , if `alpha` value is set to zero, the view is still drawn, whereas, setting a hidden property will ignore the touch events on it and hide it from view hierarchy. As they both have same effect, i am implementing both, because for some reason if hidden property is changed by dev, this `alpha` value might work

Answer (score 0):

It's not the efficient way to set a UIView hidden. You can Add SubView & RemoveFromSuperView is the optimum way.

Add it to your Super View

```
[self.mkMapView addSubview:self.mapTypeVIew];
```

To remove it from SuperView

```
[self.mapTypeVIew removeFromSuperview];
```